# How to offset().top from every $('.example p') element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, offset

I'm trying to get every offset().top value of every $('.example p') element

```
console.log($('.example p')[1].offset().top)
```

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[1].offset is not a function

I've tried a bunch of things, like using other selectors, using a for loop, foreach...
I can only get the offset().top value from the first element of that array by removing [1], for the second, third, etc... element I can't seem to get it.

Comment: What is your HTML structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate through each of the elements in the selector `".example p"` using `each`

See demo:

```js
$(".example p").each(function(i)
{
  console.log( $(this).offset().top); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example">
  <p>Doggo ipsum you are doing me a frighten corgo heckin good boys and girls pupperino, fat boi. Doing me a frighten you are doing me the shock clouds you are doin me a concern borkf super chub, wow very biscit you are doing me a frighten pupper.   you are doing me a frighten pupper porgo. Fluffer wow very biscit blop fluffer puggorino puggo very hand that feed shibe, boofers maximum borkdrive the neighborhood pupper boofers. 
  </p>

  <p>Doggo ipsum you are doing me a frighten corgo heckin good boys and girls pupperino, fat boi. Doing me a frighten you are doing me the shock clouds you are doin me a concern borkf super chub, wow very biscit you are doing me a frighten pupper.   you are doing me a frighten pupper porgo. Fluffer wow very biscit blop fluffer puggorino puggo very hand that feed shibe, boofers maximum borkdrive the neighborhood pupper boofers. 
  </p>
</div>
<div class="something">
  <p>Doggo ipsum you are doing me a frighten corgo heckin good boys and girls pupperino, fat boi. Doing me a frighten you are doing me the shock clouds you are doin me a concern borkf super chub, wow very biscit you are doing me a frighten pupper.   you are doing me a frighten pupper porgo. Fluffer wow very biscit blop fluffer puggorino puggo very hand that feed shibe, boofers maximum borkdrive the neighborhood pupper boofers. 
  </p>

  <p>Doggo ipsum you are doing me a frighten corgo heckin good boys and girls pupperino, fat boi. Doing me a frighten you are doing me the shock clouds you are doin me a concern borkf super chub, wow very biscit you are doing me a frighten pupper.   you are doing me a frighten pupper porgo. Fluffer wow very biscit blop fluffer puggorino puggo very hand that feed shibe, boofers maximum borkdrive the neighborhood pupper boofers. 
  </p>
</div>
<div class="example">
  <p>Doggo ipsum you are doing me a frighten corgo heckin good boys and girls pupperino, fat boi. Doing me a frighten you are doing me the shock clouds you are doin me a concern borkf super chub, wow very biscit you are doing me a frighten pupper.   you are doing me a frighten pupper porgo. Fluffer wow very biscit blop fluffer puggorino puggo very hand that feed shibe, boofers maximum borkdrive the neighborhood pupper boofers. 
  </p>

  <p>Doggo ipsum you are doing me a frighten corgo heckin good boys and girls pupperino, fat boi. Doing me a frighten you are doing me the shock clouds you are doin me a concern borkf super chub, wow very biscit you are doing me a frighten pupper.   you are doing me a frighten pupper porgo. Fluffer wow very biscit blop fluffer puggorino puggo very hand that feed shibe, boofers maximum borkdrive the neighborhood pupper boofers. 
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Very clean solution, thank you!

Comment: No problem. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2):

Because `$('.example p')[1]` return node HTML (element html)

If you want to get offset with jquery you can use :
`$('.example p').eq(1).offset()`

Comment: Thank you so much, can't believe how long I've been looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

It's seem that jQuery don't return an array of jQuery object. Check for example if `$('.example p')[1]` is a jQuery object. You should convert all items in jQuery object like this:

```
var allExample = $('.example p').map((i, e) => $(e))
```

And then retry:

```
console.log(allExample[1].offset())
```

Comment: "*it seems that"* - that's exactly what jquery does when you use `[1]` - it returns the DOM node, so it's no longer a jquery object.